# If I define a property to prototype appears in the constructor of object, why?

Tags: object-oriented, javascript, prototyping

I took the example from this question modified a bit:
[What is the point of the prototype method?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/106142/what-is-the-point-of-the-prototype-method)

```
function employee(name,jobtitle,born)
{
this.name=name;
this.jobtitle=jobtitle;
this.born=born;
this.status="single"
}
employee.prototype.salary=10000000;
var fred=new employee("Fred Flintstone","Caveman",1970);
console.log(fred.salary);
fred.salary=20000;
console.log(fred.salary)
```

And the output in console is this:

[image]

What is the difference `salary` is in constructor but I still can access it with `fred.salary`, how can I see if is in constructor from code, status is still employee property how can I tell for example if `name` is the one of employee or has been touch by initialization?

Why is salary in constructor, when name,jobtitle,born where "touched" by `employee("Fred Flintstone","Caveman",1970);` «constructor»?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting the prototype, you are just making an object to be shared with other instances of the same type. ie,

```
var liz = new employee('Elizabeth','Teacher',1980);
var jane = new employee('Jane','unknown',1981);
```

`liz.salary` is same as `jane.salary`, even the underlying memory will be the same.

but when you set the `salary` of an instance, you are not changing the `salary` variable in the prototype, but you are defining a new property unique for that instance. so, `fred.salary = 20000` will just **hide** the `salary` attribute of the prototype.

so `fred.salary` will make javascript engine to look for salary in the `fred` instance tree, upon which it will take the direct property of that instance.
while `liz.salary` will resolve to the property in the prototype.

I hope now the console output make some sense.

Comment: Now I see is not under the constructor tree is on the same branch in `__proto__`.